# Show counts for all months up to current month including zero counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008, datetime

My current query which is based on retrieving data for the year 2018:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, STARTDATE) AS MonthName, COUNT (*) AS TOTAL
FROM TABLEUSERS
WHERE YEAR(STARTDATE) = '2018'
GROUP BY MONTH(STARTDATE), DATENAME(MONTH,STARTDATE)
```

The result:

```
MonthName | TOTAL
January   |  25
February  |  20 
March     |  40
April     |  11 
May       |  30 
June      |  0
July      |  0 
August    |  0
September |  7
October   |  55
November  |  13
December  |  0
```

As you can see it's retrieving **December** for the year 2018 on the list and I don't want December to be shown, I am only interested to view data for all the months we've been through (November as of now).

The result must also contain months where the count is zero.

Comment: Then add a condition `AND MONTH(STARTDATE) <= MONTH(GETDATE())`

Comment: That query does not produce that result. So I'm not sure what you're asking for here.

Comment: @Squirrel This works fine, but it actually removes the months in between with zero counts too, how can I only do it with the upcoming month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 (I think) you can use the following:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, d) AS MonthName, COUNT(STARTDATE) AS Total
FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11)) AS numbers(n)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n, '2018-01-01')) AS dates(d)
LEFT JOIN TABLEUSERS ON YEAR(STARTDATE) = YEAR(d) AND MONTH(STARTDATE) = MONTH(d)
WHERE n < MONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY d
```

There is a (hard-coded) list of numbers between 0 and 11 that will allow you to generate 12 dates. Rest is straight forward.

Comment: I get this error: 'EOMONTH' is not a recognized built-in function name. Im using mSSQL

Comment: @MishMish - then specify which *version* of SQL Server you're using. Since it's been in there since the 2012 version.